# How to build a standalone SWT GUI with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, swt

In this howto https://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php there is a good guide how to build an SWT based GUI with Eclipse.
Now, I want to assemble the same project with Maven. By using the pom.xml  at the end, I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] adding entry libswt-awt-cocoa-4626.jnilib
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.747 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-12T15:06:45+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project swtsandbox: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: Problem creating jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project swtsandbox: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: Problem creating jar: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
```

The pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pmu</groupId>
  <artifactId>swtsandbox</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>swtsandbox</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <swt.version>4.6.1</swt.version>
  </properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-eclipse-repo</id>
        <url>http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- select prefered one, or move the preferred on to the top: -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
            <version>${swt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
            <version>${swt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>



<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>pmu.swtsandbox.App</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
p
```

Comment: Define the version of maven-assembly-plugin and furthermore which Maven version do you use? Running from plain console? Or from inside Eclipse?

Comment: the idea is to build  an application headless (i.e. command line) - for maven see edits

Comment: Have you turned on to verify checksums via `mvn -C ...`...first step is simply to delete your whole local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` and rebuild your application....

Comment: thanks indeed the problem was there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like one or more of the jars in your local `.m2` Maven Repository got corrupted (`jar-with-dependencies` attempts to unpack all your dependencies first, in order to bundle them in the same jar).

Unfortunately, the error message doesn't say which.

You can either:

- Remove the entirety of the contents of your `.m2` repository, and rely on Maven downloading them again (the `.m2` repository is found, on a Windows setup, in your current user folder; for example for me this is located at `C:\Users\Andrei\.m2`)
- Re-run your build with `-X` option which *should* offer more details on which particular jar is causing the problem. Then you can only delete that one.

Unless you have any custom `install`s in your `.m2` folder, I advise option 1.